# Build error SQL46005: Expected FILESTREAM_ON but encountered object instead when trying to build a database project for Azure Synapse SQL pool

Tags: sql, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to build a database project with azure synapse sql pool as the target database but i get `Build error SQL46005: Expected FILESTREAM_ON but encountered object instead` error every time single.

I investigated as noticed there are couple procedures where I am using the data swapping approach to stage and load the data. Here is an example of the pattern;

```
CREATE PROC [schema].[some_proc] AS

-- Drop temp table if exists
if object_id(N'schema.t_dim_temp_table') is not null
drop table schema.t_dim_temp_table;

create table schema.t_dim_temp_table
with (   distribution = hash (somecol)
        ,clustered columnstore index
     )
as
select
*
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS last_update_date
from stgschema.v_dim_stage

-- Rename and remove temp objects
rename object schema.t_dim_table       to t_dim_table_old;
rename object schema.t_dim_temp_table  to t_dim_table;
drop table schema.t_dim_table_old;
```

Any ideas about how to get around this error will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this issue by wrapping it in an `Exec` function.

```
Exec('rename object schema.t_dim_table       to t_dim_table_old');
Exec('rename object schema.t_dim_temp_table  to t_dim_table');
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that will solve your issue but the rename works without the schema in the "to" part:

- rename object schema.t_dim_table            to t_dim_table_old;
- rename object schema.t_dim_temp_table       to t_dim_table;

Best,
Ingo